# Unable to open project in design/code mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, user-controls

If have BIG software package that check for licence serial number upon starting.
Normally that app wont start unitll correct licence number is entered (real or trial one)

The problem here is that I can not even open the code in Visual Studio (design or code mode) if I don't provide licence details.

I know that licence form (where user enters licence details) is in a form of UserControl.

Questiono is :

**Which part of VisualStudio defines code to be run UPION opening form in design/code window ?**

Is it `csproj` file or ?
I am aware of `post-build` or `pre-build` tasks but this code run before I am open the package to start my coding !!!!

ps: here is the code I found in my project.csproj

where NewLicenseForm is actually the form used to enter reg details.
How can I disable this form from firing upon opening project in design mode ?

```
<Compile Include="NewLicenseForm.cs">
<SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="NewLicenseForm.Designer.cs">
<DependentUpon>NewLicenseForm.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="NewLicenseInfo.cs" />
<EmbeddedResource Include="NewLicenseForm.resx">
<DependentUpon>NewLicenseForm.cs</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

Comment: Are there any plugins/add-ins installed modifying how VS is working? What is the software package?

Comment: Are you sure Visual Studio properly installed? (cos of interrupts during installation) If not Try to repair the installation and see

Comment: The designer runs code at design time as well.  The DesignMode property indicates the state.  Clearly you should contact the vendor or author of this product for guidance.

Comment: unfortunately there is no "vendor"  i could contact. I took over the project from another developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to do but from NewLicenceForm. Just check in it if form is in `DesignMode` - it is a form property (more info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx)). In `DesignMode` just not run your code.